# Node.js TCP Connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, tcp

I am trying to write a Node.js app that will perform TCP connections to some TCP/IP modules we use in the office. These modules are installed in old consoles and therefore the software to manage them is very old and it is no longer supported. The way we operate them now is to use the command prompt in Windows and connect to them that way. Here is how we are currently doing it.

```
>telnet <XX.XX.XX.XX> <PORT>
```

if the connection is successful then we get a blank screen in which we then type

```
<Ctrl+A> 200
```

Where  is holding the Ctrl key and the A key at the same time, followed by the number 200. It then pops out some simple details about the module, which is what we want. This method works for us, but the problem is that it is not practical when you have 20+ of these modules each with different IPs. We have to connect to them every week to make sure they are working and doing 20 of them really takes up a lot of your time, so we want to optimize the process. We began writing a mini app in Node.js that takes care of the connections

```js
var net = require('net');

var HOST_ARR = ['XX.XX.XX.XX'];
var PORT = 10001;

var client = new net.Socket();

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn('cmd');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});


function connect(host, port){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    client.connect(port, host, function() {
        // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected
        console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + host + ':' + port);

        /*** EXECUTE <Ctrl+A> 200 COMMAND BEFORE CLOSING THE CONNECTION ***/

        resolve('Success');
        //end connection
        client.destroy();
    });
    //handle errors
    client.on('error', function(err) {
      reject(err.code);
    });
  });
}
```

We are able to connect to the modules just fine, and the process is extremely fast. We are just stuck on how to execute the `command <Ctrl+A> 200` once the connection starts. Any suggestions?

I tried

```js
exec('\0x01200', function(error, stdout, stderr) { //ASCII for <Ctrl+A> is \0x01
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
       console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

but did not work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about just sending `<Ctrl+A>200` by `client` after connected Like:

```
client.write(new Buffer([
  0x01, // Ctrl-A
  0x32, // 2
  0x30, // 0
  0x30, // 0
  // uncomment if necessary
  // 0x0d, // \r
  // 0x0a, // \n
]));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This partly solves the problem, however I only get one line response instead of the whole thing. Is there a way to read the whole incoming data?

Comment: `client.destroy()` may shutdown the connection before the whole incoming data is received. What if `client.destroy()` is replaced with `client.end()` in your code ?